# How can I have my pc comunicate over ethernet with mbed NXP LPC 1768

Tags: mbed

I'm an engineering student, and to be honest a beginner in drivers writing. What i'm trying to achieve right here, is have the titular board talk with my pc over ethernet, so i'm asking for some useful tips regarding the communication setup, like pinging it from my pc.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since LPC1768 doesn't come with a RJ45 jack, you need to somehow connect a RJ45 jack to your mbed. This page may be helpful. https://os.mbed.com/cookbook/Ethernet-RJ45

Once you have physical connection, connecting a mbed device to internet is pretty easy with Mbed OS EthernetInterface library. You can find API and examples here. https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/apis/ethernet.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Ethernet? Why not using USART directly by using e.g. use a USART to USB converter like the [FTDI](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) chip.